# Move constructor is not called when using boost::pool_allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, move-semantics, boost-pool

I have the following simple test code.

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp"

struct Frame
{
    uint32_t i{};

    Frame(uint32_t _i) : i(_i) {}

    Frame(const Frame& f)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
        i = f.i;
    }

    Frame(Frame&& f)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;
        std::swap(i, f.i);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    {
        std::stack<Frame, std::deque<Frame>> stack;

        Frame f(0);
        stack.push(std::move(f)); // Move constructor
        stack.push(Frame(1)); // Move constructor
    }

    {
        std::stack<Frame, std::deque<Frame, boost::pool_allocator<Frame>>> stack;

        Frame f(0);
        stack.push(std::move(f)); // Copy constructor
        stack.push(Frame(1)); // Copy constructor
    }


    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code with either Clang or GCC, it gives me the following output:

```
Move constructor
Move constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
```

Why does using `boost::pool_allocator` prevent the compiler from using the move constructor?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pool_allocator` does not perfect forward the arguments to `construct`: It simply takes a `const` reference to the value type and passes that on as the initializer for placement `new`.

That is because `pool_allocator` has not been updated for C++11 yet.